# (у)слышать звуки — плеоназм или нет?

Tags: плеоназм

Очень часто можно увидеть/услышать такие конструкции: "услышать звуки шагов", "услышанные звуки", "услышать звучание" и подобные этим. Являются ли они ошибочными? Ведь данный глагол и производное от него своим значением подразумевают восприятие звуков.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, не является. Услышать, кроме звуков, можно ещё и запах, хоть это выражение и устаревает.